# How to get BlendSpace2D states from AnimationTree node in Godot using C#?

Tags: c#, godot

So I'm currently trying to learn game development with Godot using C# by following along with this tutorial:

[Godot tutorial - the part that I'm up to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9aR9IiiHT8)

Unfortunately the code is in GDScript, so I've been converting it to C# along the way. I've tried to use an AnimationTree node with the player, which has two BlendSpace2D states (for Idle states and Run states).In the Player script, the childs should be referenced, so that the animation frames change as the character moves.
I've tried to locate previously answered stack overflow questions for this, but can't seem to find any.
So far my code looks like this:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Player : KinematicBody2D
{
    //CHARACTER MOVING STUFF
    public const int run_acc = 80;
    public const int max_speed = 100;
    public const int friction = 500;
    
    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(); //xy position combined
    //ANIMATION PLAYER
    private AnimationPlayer _animationPlayer; //gets animationPlayer node from Player object
    public AnimationTree _animationTree;
    public AnimationTree _animationState;
    // onready var animationState = _animationTree.Get("parameters/playback");
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        _animationPlayer = GetNode<AnimationPlayer>("AnimationPlayer");
        _animationTree = GetNode<AnimationTree>("AnimationTree");
        _animationState = GetNode<AnimationTree>("parameters/playback");
    }

    public override void _PhysicsProcess(float delta) // delta has time for last frame processed
    { 
        //moving char
        var input_vector = Vector2.Zero;
        input_vector.x = ((Input.GetActionStrength("move_right")) - Input.GetActionStrength("move_left"));
        input_vector.y = ((Input.GetActionStrength("move_down")) - Input.GetActionStrength("move_up"));
        input_vector = input_vector.Normalized(); // stops diagonal speed inc
        
        if (input_vector != Vector2.Zero) { //moving
            _animationTree.Set("parameters/idle/blend_position", input_vector);
            _animationTree.Set("parameters/run/blend_position", input_vector);
            _animationState.Travel("Run"); // FIRST ERROR HERE
            velocity = velocity.MoveToward(input_vector * max_speed, run_acc);

        } else {
            _animationState.Travel("Idle"); //SECOND ERROR HERE
            velocity = velocity.MoveToward(Vector2.Zero, friction * delta);
        }
        velocity = MoveAndSlide(velocity);
    }
}
```

Both errors state: "C:\Users\x\Documents\GitHub\godot_game\Player.cs(35,20): 'AnimationTree' does not contain a definition for 'Travel' and no accessible extension method 'Travel' accepting a first argument of type 'AnimationTree' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that your _animationState does not have the right type.

In the tutorial he uses the "Get" function to get the value of the parameter "playback"

Because the Get function can return a huge variety of diffrent objects it itself returns a object of the base class "object", which you need to cast to the appropriate class you need.

In this case the object for "parameters/playback" is of the type AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback (you see the type in the inspector under Parameters/Playback).

So your code has to look like this:

```
 public AnimationTree _animationTree;
 public AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback _animationState;

 public override void _Ready()
 {
     _animationPlayer = GetNode<AnimationPlayer>("AnimationPlayer");
     _animationTree = GetNode<AnimationTree>("AnimationTree");
     var playback = _animationTree.Get("parameters/playback");
     if (playback != null && playback is AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback)
        _animationState = playback as AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback;
 }
```

Get returns null, if the parameter was not found. My if statement just makes sure, that I'm really able to cast the returned object to the type AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback.

Because AnimationNodeStateMachinePlayback has the function Travel you are trying to use, the errors should be vanish.